# Parameters for a Levy distribution in R

Tags: r, parameters, statistics, distribution, data-fitting

Can someone help me figure out how I can get parameter estimates for a levy distribution using R? Unlike the normal distribution and Student T distribution which has functions `nFit(x)`from the package `fBasics` and `stdFit(x)` respectively from package `fGarch`, the Levy distribution doesn't seem to have the same ability. I am trying to fit my data set to the levy distribution so I need a function in R that will give me good estimates for the delta and gamma parameters.

I was able to use the `fBasics` and `fGarch` packages to calculate the parameters(mu and sigma) for a normal distribution and (mu, sd, and nu) for a symmetric student T distribution. Now I am looking to calculate the following parameters for a Levy distribution : delta and gamma. Delta is the location parameter and gamma is the scale parameter.

I tried to use the `fitdistr`function from `MASS` to fit it by doing the following:

```
> fitdistr(x,dlevy,list(m = 0, s = 1))
Error in densfun(x, parm[1], parm[2], ...) : some y <= m
```

however, now I am stuck. I keep getting the above "Error" message. Assuming there is no built in function for the Levy distribution, any ideas how to proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `levy` function in the `VGAM` package is what you are looking for ([click](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/VGAM/docs/levy)).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought that was what I would need except I do not know how to use that function. I do not understand the inputs. For example, I do not understand "link.gamma" nor how the function takes in my data array, x.